# Control pwm with push button

Tags: c++, arduino, pwm

I'm new to arduino and I have been trying to control pwm with push buttons. My task is to change the PWM of pin 3~ to different values when different buttons is pressed (button 1: 25%, button 2 : 50%, button 3 : 75%, and 0 when no button is pressed) and print out the length of HIGH value in pin 3. But when I don't press any button it still print out some weird number (I expect it to print out 0) and when I push any button the value doesn't change (around 1595-1605). Any idea how to fix it?
Video when I try to run it
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16lE8LDmHdlz0SbHj0AGGMQ8nNEcT8rIT/view?usp=sharing

````
//
int button1 = 8;
int LED1 = 2;
int button2 = 11;
int LED2 = 4;
int button3 = 12;
int LED3 = 7;
int pwm3 = 3;
int pwm3V;
unsigned long duration;
void setup()
{
 pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(8, INPUT);
 pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(11, INPUT);
 pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(12, INPUT);
 pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
 if (digitalRead(button1)== HIGH)//Press Button 1   
     {
       digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);  
       pwm3V = 64;//pwm value 25%
     }
 if (digitalRead(button1)== LOW)// Unpress Button 1
     {
       digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
       pwm3V = 0;//pwm value

     }
 if (digitalRead(button2)== HIGH)//Press Button 2
     {
       digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
       pwm3V = 64*2;//pwm value 50%
     }
 if (digitalRead(button2)== LOW)// Unpress Button 2
     {
      digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
       pwm3V = 0;//pwm value

     }
 if (digitalRead(button3)== HIGH)// Press Button 3
     {
       digitalWrite(LED3, HIGH);
       pwm3V = 64*3;//pwm value 75%
     }
 if (digitalRead(button3)== LOW)// Unpress Button 3
     {
       digitalWrite(LED3, LOW);
       pwm3V = 0;//pwm value
     }
 analogWrite(pwm3, pwm3V); //set pwm value
 duration = pulseIn(pwm3, HIGH);
 Serial.print(duration); //print lenght of HIGH
       
} ```
````

Answer (score 2):

The value of the variable `pwm3V` will always be `0` unless `button3` is pressed at the right time; the problem is in the control structure. Since a pull-up resistor is used in the circuit diagram of the buttons, when the button is pressed, a low signal is read on the Arduino Board.

In the solution I developed below, I took your source code as a basis, but I made extensive edits. I made things easier by defining the button and led pins as a series. I checked if the pins are low level to check the button pressed status. I designed a control mechanism using the `loopControl` variable so that the output is not cleared in the iteration after the button is pressed.

```cpp
int buttonPins[] = {8, 11, 12}, ledPins[] = {2, 4, 7}, pwmPin = 3;
size_t size = sizeof(buttonPins)/sizeof(buttonPins[0]);
int pwmOutputValue;
unsigned long duration, loopControl;

void setup(){
    for(size_t i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i){
        pinMode(buttonPins[i], INPUT);
        pinMode(ledPins[i], OUTPUT);
    }
    pinMode(pwmPin, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

int readButtons(){    
    for(size_t index = 0 ; index < size ; ++index)
        if(digitalRead(buttonPins[index]) == LOW)
            return index;
    return -1;
}

void updatePWMValue(){
    analogWrite(pwmOutputValue, pwmPin);
    duration = pulseIn(pwmOutputValue, HIGH);
    Serial.print(duration);
}

void loop(){
    int result = readButtons();
    
    if(result != -1){
        digitalWrite(result, HIGH);
        pwmOutputValue = 64 * result;
    }
    else {
      if(++loopControl > 100000){ // If this line is cancelled, the whole state is updated in the first cycle after the button is pressed.
        for(size_t i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i)
            digitalWrite(ledPins[i], LOW);

        pwmOutputValue = 0;
        loopControl = 0;
      }
    }
    updatePWMValue();
}
```

Comment: <The value of the variable pwm3V will always be 0 unless button3 is pressed at the right time; the problem is in the control structure.> Why is that?
<Since a pull-up resistor is used in the circuit diagram of the buttons, when the button is pressed, a low signal is read on the Arduino Board.> I think the same but when I use 
if (digitalRead(button1)== HIGH)//Press Button 1   
     {
       digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
The LED still light up.

Comment: Either the `digitalRead(button_x)== HIGH` condition or the `digitalRead(button_x)== LOW` condition is always `true`. In this case, even if button1 or button2 is clicked, button3's state determines the result.

Comment: If you examine the breadboard, you will see that the 3.3V line is connected to the **(-)** line and GND is connected to the **(+)** line. In this case, when the button is not pressed, the Arduino Board reads a voltage of 3.3V. When the button is pressed, Arduino Board reads voltage at GND level.